# Consuming a JAX-WS webservice in enterprise environment

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, apache-axis

**The task:**
I am working on a J2EE application in an Enterprise environment with WAS runtime. I have to consume the already developed JAX-WS web service by the organization and I have been provided just a wsdl to proceed. So to test the service I created a project; copied wsdl into it and then generated the client. My project was then populated with a bunch of java classes. I tested the service successfully writing a main class and making calls to the service endpoint.

**The problem:**
Now when I try to call this web service in my already existing web project by including the webservice jar which is available from the Ivy repository we have, into the classpath then I am not able to run the same service instead I get an exception:

`javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException
(at /definitions/message[1]/part): faultCode=UNBOUND_PREFIX: Unable to
determine namespace of 'tns:getUserResponse'`

After debugging I found that the error occurs at the point where I create a Service instance using URL and QName:
`Service#create(URL wsdlDocumentLocation, QName serviceName)`
which gets caught into WebServiceException class.

**Research:**
I have tried searching for similar error messages but only found this comment which I do not fully understand:
`This problem occurs when the thrown exception is in a different package from the service interface, and the exception is not in java.lang.* or in javax.*. When all of these apply, the WSDL generated by Axis2 1.2 refers to an undefined namespace prefix.`

I am looking for replies from "Been there done that" kind of experienced people. I understand this problem could be too localized.

**PS:** There is nothing wrong with the wsdl; other apps in the organization are using it.

**Full Stack Trace:**

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException(at /definitions/message[1]/part): faultCode=UNBOUND_PREFIX: Unable to determine namespace of 'tns:getUserResponse'.
org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:175)
org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)
org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:128)
org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.loadDefinition(WSDL4JWrapper.java:741)
org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.getDefinition(WSDL4JWrapper.java:657)
org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.commonPartsURLConstructor(WSDL4JWrapper.java:224)
org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.<init>(WSDL4JWrapper.java:156)
org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.setupWsdlDefinitionServiceDescriptionImpl.java:1182)
org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.<init>(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:249)
org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.<init>(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:172)
org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:143)
org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:79)
org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.DescriptionFactory.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactory.java:78)
org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegate.<init>(ServiceDelegate.java:218)
org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.Provider.createServiceDelegate(Provider.java:83)
org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.Provider.createServiceDelegate(Provider.java:79)
javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57)
javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:687)
com.myexample.project.security.servlet.MyAdapter.authenticateUser(MyAdapter.java:39)
com.myexample.project.security.servlet.AbstractLoginServlet.doLogin(AbstractLoginServlet.java:244)
com.myexample.project.security.servlet.AbstractLoginServlet.doPost(AbstractLoginServlet.java:341)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1214)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1027)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3703)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:522)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:311)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:282)
com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1783)
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException (at /definitions/message[1]/part):faultCode=UNBOUND_PREFIX: Unable to determine namespace of 'tns:getUserResponse'.
com.ibm.wsdl.util.xml.DOMUtils.getQName(DOMUtils.java:309)
com.ibm.wsdl.util.xml.DOMUtils.getQualifiedAttributeValue(DOMUtils.java:367)
com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getQualifiedAttributeValue(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2146)
com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parsePart(WSDLReaderImpl.java:1345)
com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseMessage(WSDLReaderImpl.java:1324)
com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseDefinitions(WSDLReaderImpl.java:357)
com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2409)
com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2373)
com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2426)
com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2334)
com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2296)
org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper$13.run(WSDL4JWrapper.java:732)
org.apache.axis2.java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:132)
org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.loadDefinition(WSDL4JWrapper.java:729)
... 43 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a lot of errors to resolve. I was missing the client jar file to be put in the project in which I was using the web service and then I needed to specify the `JVM parameters` using the WAS Administrative console. I was putting it in a wrong place.

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\IBM\RAD85\jdk\jre\lib\security\cacerts 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```